# Query plan not using indexes with $exists

Tags: mongodb, database-performance

I'm running MongoDB 3.0 and I have a collection that has (among others) the following indexes:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "run_state" : 1
    },
    "name" : "run_state_1",
    "ns" : "xxx.yyyy"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "visibility_state" : 1
    },
    "name" : "visibility_state",
    "ns" : "xxx.yyyy"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "affiliate_id" : "hashed"
    },
    "name" : "affiliate_id_hashed",
    "ns" : "xxx.yyyy"
}
```

I need get all documents that matches some conditions.
One of them is the existence of `affiliate_id` field.

If I have a query that includes the `$exists` operator and other conditions, like:

```
db.getCollection('campaigns')
  .find({
    affiliate_id : { $exists : true }, 
    visibility_state : 'showing', 
    run_state : 'running'
  })
  .explain()
```

I get the following execution plan:

```
{
  "winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
          "filter" : {
            "$and" : [ 
              {
                "visibility_state" : {
                  "$eq" : "showing"
                }
              }, 
              {
                "affiliate_id" : {
                  "$exists" : true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN", // GOOD, it uses the index (:
              "keyPattern" : {
                "run_state" : 1
              },
              "indexName" : "run_state_1",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "run_state" : [ 
                  "[\"running\", \"running\"]"
                ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

So the query will use the index and will perform very fast.

However, if the query includes only the `$exists` operator, I get:

```
{
  "winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "COLLSCAN", // Full collection scan D:
      "filter" : {
        "affiliate_id" : {
          "$exists" : true
        }
      },
      "direction" : "forward"
  },
}
```

So this query will ignore the index and perform a full collection scan and will perform very poorly.

If I use `$ne : null` instead, the results are the same as above.

---

I understand that in the first case, the index lookup will happen only in the `run_state` field and the next phase will just filter out the fetched data.

I'm just wondering why Mongo doesn't use the index for `$exists` or `$ne : null`.

---

## Edit

As @lascort suggested in the comments, I've changed the type of the index to be a regular sorted one. And now the index is used, but it still has this filter stage.

```
{
  "winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
          "filter" : {
            "affiliate_id" : {
              "$exists" : true
            }
          },
          "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern" : {
                "affiliate_id" : 1.0
              },
              "indexName" : "affiliate_id_1",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "affiliate_id" : [ 
                  "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                ]
              }
          }
      }
  },
}
```

I have also created a compound index with `run_state`, `visibility_state` and `affiliate_id` keys while keeping the single ones. If i run a query containing the 3 fields, I get the same as before creating the compound index, with a FETCH stage containing a FILTER operation:

```
{
  "winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
          "filter" : {
            "$and" : [ 
              {
                "visibility_state" : {
                  "$eq" : "showing"
                }
              }, 
              {
                "affiliate_id" : {
                  "$exists" : true
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern" : {
                "run_state" : 1.0
              },
              "indexName" : "run_state_1",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "run_state" : [ 
                  "[\"running\", \"running\"]"
                ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
},
```

If I drop the 3 single indexes, then I get this:

```
{
  "winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
      "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "FETCH",
          "filter" : {
            "affiliate_id" : {
              "$exists" : true
            }
          },
          "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
              "keyPattern" : {
                "visibility_state" : 1.0,
                  "run_state" : 1.0,
                  "affiliate_id" : 1.0
              },
              "indexName" : "visibility_state_1_run_state_1_affiliate_id_1",
              "isMultiKey" : false,
              "direction" : "forward",
              "indexBounds" : {
                "visibility_state" : [ 
                  "[\"showing\", \"showing\"]"
                ],
                  "run_state" : [ 
                    "[\"running\", \"running\"]"
                  ],
                  "affiliate_id" : [ 
                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Which seems to be more efficient.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on, as to why it won't use the index, but it seems to be a problem with the `affiliate_id` index being `hashed`. If you create a regular index instead it will work fine. On another subject.. for your first query you should consider using a compound index, it should perform better than only using the run_state index. And for your second query (the one with only `$exists: true` condition) a sparse index sounds good.

Comment: Thank's @lascort, a regular index did it! :D About the compound indexes, should I create a new one or consider merging this 3 into 1? What is the marginal overhead of adding a new index to mongo?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your comment here since it will be easier to read and it will probably take more than 600 characters.

As for whether you should create a new, compound index and discard the others or keep them is really dependent on a bunch of variables, like how many other indexes you have, how big are your collections, what's your hardware configuration, etc.

Taking that into consideration, if your plan is to create a single compound index for all your queries then you really need to think ahead and keep in mind what a compound index is able to do. For example..

`db.collection.createIndex({field1: 1, field2: 1})` will not produce the same results as `db.collection.createIndex({field2: 1, field1: 1})`. If you create the later your queries filtering only by `field1` won't use the index.

But focusing more in your scenario.. if you create an index with fields `run_state`, `affiliate_id`, `visibility_state` in that order. Your queries with JUST the condition `{$exists: false}` also won't use the index. I will quote the mongo documentation to explain this further.

> **Prefixes**
>
> Index prefixes are the beginning subsets of indexed fields. For
>   example, consider the following compound index:
>
> ```
> { "item": 1, "location": 1, "stock": 1 }
> ```
>
> The index has the following index prefixes:
>
> ```
> { item: 1 }
> { item: 1, location: 1 }
> ```
>
> For a compound index, MongoDB can
>   use the index to support queries on the index prefixes. As such,
>   MongoDB can use the index for queries on the following fields:
>
> - the item field
> - the item field and the location field
> - the item field and the location field and the stock field
>
> MongoDB can also use the
>   index to support a query on item and stock fields since item field
>   corresponds to a prefix. However, the index would not be as efficient
>   in supporting the query as would be an index on only item and stock.
>
> However, MongoDB cannot use the index to support queries that include
>   the following fields since without the item field, none of the listed
>   fields correspond to a prefix index:
>
> - the location field,
> - the stock field, or
> - the location and stock fields.

Here's a link to that part of the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/index-compound/